# How do I install lubuntu? (kernel panic)

Tags: installation, intel-graphics, lubuntu

Please help me install Lubuntu 12.04 i386 on an old computer. I select the "Try Lubuntu without installing" and it crashes with a kernel panic. Rarely I do get to the live OS, but soon the display goes blank. The messages log gives me '[drm] ERROR GPU hung/wedged' The specs are:

Pentium 4 2.4GHz
1GB DDR RAM
40GB PATA HDD
Intel 845GL chipset (8MB framebuffer, 64MB shared system memory set in the BIOS)

Comment: Did you [MD5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the ISO?

Comment: Try booting it with the 'nomodset' options. Intel's 8xx graphics chips are known to cause such problems. Check out <http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup.html> Solution 2 for how to use boot options with a live CD.

Comment: In addition to MD5summing the `.iso` as [Mitch](http://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch) suggests and trying [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) as [mikewhatever](http://askubuntu.com/users/20054/mikewhatever) suggests, you should check the installation media (whether it's USB or CD/DVD) with [this procedure](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure this would be any help, but, I fought with my older machine trying to install 12.04, Couldnt get the cd's to work period. But, when I put the i386 on a flash drive and booted from that, it worked peachy. http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: Tried that. It boots from pen drive, but after I select the live cd option, it just gives a blank screen. Sorry, that modesetting tutorial does not load. I've also checked the disc, no errors. Any ideas?

Comment: I read that the hardware itself is buggy and old drivers used to ignore those buggy features. New drivers use the buggy features, hence cause a crash. Hmm.

Comment: Maybe I need to get a PCI VGA card?